# Android Studio - Set RGB on a button

Tags: android, android-button, android-color, rgbcolor

i'm programming in Android with Android Studio and I need to set a color of the RGB scale on a button (not in the xml but with in the java code). How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your rgb code in this website http://www.rgbtohex.net/ and with the hex code (the one that starts with #) use:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(hexcodefromwebsite));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);
```

button.setBackground(R.color.YOUR_COLOR_RESOURCE);

Comment: thanks, I have another question: how can I set the color using the values R G and B ?